# lighttpd server execute script when someone is connected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lighttpd

Hello i have a lighttpd server runnig on my pi.
I want to know how to execute a script every time someone connect to my site ...
I tried with accesslog, but maybe you know an easier way?

Comment: Yea, it's called `cgi` in most web server software and the [docs](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModCGI) have a lot on it.

Comment: Can you show what you’ve tried so far, and where you’ve gotten stuck?

Comment: I am already using CGI for the user to activate programs in .c or .py or ... but what I want is that when someone connects the server activates a prog by itself.
I think => read the file '/ var / log / lighttpd / accesslog' and if a line (new user) appears => call a script ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, similar to your responses to comments.  Please edit your question to **add more details** on what you are trying to do.

mod_accesslog is a **log** and records access.  mod_accesslog **by itself** is **absolutely not** what you want.  There are third-party programs (independent from lighttpd) such as fail2ban which watch the accesslog, but your intentions remain unclear and I am guessing that is not your aim.

mod_accesslog can also log to a pipe, and the other end of the pipe can be a program of your choosing which parses each line that it receives.  You might use this if the processing you want to do is independent of the response you serve to the client.  Again, this is independent of lighttpd, beyond lighttpd mod_accesslog connecting to a pipe, spawing a piped logger program once (connected to said pipe), and sending access logs to the pipe.

On the other hand, if your script is producing part of the response to the client, then you should use one of lighttpd's dynamic backends (mod_cgi, mod_fastcgi, mod_scgi, mod_proxy, mod_wstunnel, ...) to direct the request to your code.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ConfigurationOptions

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer.what I am specifically trying to do is to anticipate loading a streaming video file (.ts) in a buffer folder so that the user does not have to undergo latency if he decides to go to Streaming page and he starts just then... I manage the streaming files with a transcoding via ffmpeg and a rstp from an IP camera. I do not want to let the process run all the time but just start it when a client is connected so as not to overload the processor of the machine.

Comment: If visiting page X suggests that the user will soon visit page Y, then you can write some javascript into page X which executes on the client side and makes a background request to trigger priming the streamer.